# Juniper ZTP DHCP Server Setup

Tags: dhcp, juniper, juniper-srx, juniper-ex

I am currently trying to configure DHCP as part of a ztp setup. Right now my topology is as follows:

ex2200(me0,10.0.20.2)->(ge-0/0/1,10.0.20.1)srx100(fe-0/0/2,10.0.80.1)<-(eth0,10.0.80.2)centos6.7_dhcp_server

I have the dhcp server on the 10.0.80.0/24 subnet, and I want it to assign IP addresses into the 10.0.20.0/24 subnet.

```
set vendor-string = option vendor-class-identifier;
option space ZTPDEMO;
option ZTPDEMO.image-file-name code 0 = text;
option ZTPDEMO.config-file-name code 1 = text;
option ZTPDEMO.image-file-type code 2 = text;
option ZTPDEMO.transfer-mode code 3 = text;
option ZTPDEMO-encapsulation code 43 = encapsulate ZTPDEMO;
option ZTPDEMO.image-file-type "symlink";
option option-150 code 150 = ip-address;

host CAN1 {
 hardware ethernet 80:ac:ac:4c:84:ff;
 fixed-address 10.0.20.3;
 option host-name "to-mdf-ex22-sw5";
 option vendor-class-identifier "Juniper-ex2200-48p-4g;
 option option-150 10.0.80.2;
 option ZTPDEMO.transfer-mode "http";
 option ZTPDEMO.config-file-name "to-mdf-ex22-sw5-config.txt";
 option ZTPDEMO.image-file-name "jinstall-ex-2200-15.1R5.5-domestic-signed.tgz";
}
subnet 10.0.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;
 option routers 10.0.20.1;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;
 authoritative;
 option ZTPDEMO.transfer-mode "http";
 pool {
        range dynamic-bootp 10.0.20.3 10.0.20.254;
        option OPTION-150 10.0.80.2;
        option P61.config-file-name "default-ex2200-c-12p.config";
      }
}
```

And here is the error I receive:

```
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.1.1-P1
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2010 Internet Systems Consortium.
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Not searching LDAP since ldap-server, ldap-port and ldap-base-dn were not specified in the config file
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Wrote 0 deleted host decls to leases file.
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Wrote 0 new dynamic host decls to leases file.
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: 
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: No subnet declaration for eth0 (10.0.80.2).
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: 
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: 
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: 
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: This version of ISC DHCP is based on the release available
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: on ftp.isc.org.  Features have been added and other changes
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: have been made to the base software release in order to make
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: it work better with this distribution.
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: 
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: Please report for this software via the CentOS Bugs Database:
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd:     http://bugs.centos.org/
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: 
Feb 15 06:26:35 localhost dhcpd: exiting.
[root@localhost dhcp]# service ssh start
```

A few other tidbits: iptables is off, and the port is configured statically on the server: eth0 10.0.80.2 255.255.255.0, gateway 10.0.80.1.

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I may have solved part of the issue: I expanded the subnet netmask to cover both subnets in question and I no longer have issues with starting dhcpd, but my switch isn't getting an IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, solution found. Expanded subnet, and made some config changes on srx (had ports configured for wrong family).

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.